# how to get single value by using entity framework

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have a

```
     table product with colums product_id 
                               prodcut_name
                               category_id

                another table  category 
                               category_id
                               category_name
```

and i  am populating these product details using datagridview that working fine

and i need to get the categoryname for selected row in datagridview for that i have done like this....

```
        private void productGridview_Cellclick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
               string productname = Convert.ToString(selectedRow.Cells["productnam"].Value);
               var categoryids = from cats in abc.products
                                where cats.product_Name.Equals(productname)
                                select cats.category_Id;


            var catogynames = from categorytypes in abc.categories
                              where categorytypes.category_Name.Equals(categoryids)
                              select categorytypes.category_Name;


            string categorynames = catogynames;    

       }
```

got an

```
  error : cannot implicitly convert type sysytem.linq.iqueryble<string> to string ...
```

what i need to do to get the single category name for selected cell in productgridview productnam column

any suggestions.. pls ..

many thanks....

**Modified Code:**
               got an error :

```
not supported exception:

Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your query is returning a query object that behaves like a collection. You can use `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Single`, or `SingleOrDefault` to retrieve the first or single item from the query respectively.

```
var categoryid = (from cats in abc.products
                  where cats.product_Name.Equals(productname)
                  select cats.category_Id).SingleOrDefault();


string categoryname = (from categorytypes in abc.categories
                       where categorytypes.category_Name.Equals(categoryid)
                       select categorytypes.category_Name).SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: thanq .. can u do one more favour for me ....Is it possible to define the mapping relationships programatically by using entity and c#..

I want to specify the foreign key for one table programmatically .. is it possible ..  do u have any idea.....

Comment: A better solution is to use a navigation property like `select product.Category.category_name`, reducing this to one simple query.

Answer (score 0):

your problem with casting is here

```
  string categorynames = catogynames;
```

`catogynames` is `IQueryble`. You can do something like this,

```
List<String> categorynames = catogynames.ToList();
```

Or you can iterate through `catogynames`.

P.S please review your variable names :D.

Comment: how can i do that because i want to send one value to another form depends on datagridview  cell click

Comment: got an error at this statement      List<string> categoriess = catogynames.ToList(); cannot implicitly convert type system.collections.generics.list<char> to  system.collections.generics.list<string>  would you pls take a look at this one..

Comment: think of catogynames as of collection. And of course you can iterate through it using foreach. If you need some single value from it you can get it without foreach, just by filtering with where keyword.

Comment: You got error because categorytypes.category_Name is char. In this case you need List<char> categorynames = catogynames.ToList();